# How to call the JSON service in Secure Manner in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json

Hello i have certern API's which i am getting from service providers. The keys contains secured ID and password that we need to send with every request of API through JSON.

Presently i am using

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : {'UserName':'abce','Password':'Password'}
    success: function(results){
    console.log(results);
    }
});
```

So is there any way that i dont want to show that in the JSON request. I am creating application in ASP.NET. can you suggest me what we can do to encrypt that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way if you make the call from javascript. One possibility is to have a server side script on your domain which will act as a bridge. You could then send the AJAX request to your script which in turn will delegate the call to the remote service. You don't need JSONP in this case.

Comment: Can i use JSON.NET ? Also will that support asyn call to that API ?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way for that.

You can hide the traveling information if you go through an https (witch provides you hardware based encryption for the tunnel). -> this avoids listening, but not middleman if the SSL will be provided by him

I suggest that you should use sessions + httponly cookies what makes sense in this case. Even the session will be captured, the identity can't be hacked. Put the communication over https and you did what you can.

[If the API is provided by 3rd party - then you have no chance at all]